# PHP Cookies works well on localhost, but it's not working on live server

Tags: php, cookies, localhost

> Note: This issue is already solved,
>   finally I found that it's not cookies
>   problem, the problem is on
>   unserialize() function. The serialized
>   cookie which being the parameter of
>   that function must be stripslash-ed
>   first.

Hi there, I have a problem here about PHP Cookies. I'm using PHP Cookies to save user preferences. I've tested my code on my local machine (localhost using XAMPP). Everything's works very well, including the cookies. But when I uploaded it to the live server, the cookies not working at all. It seems that the setcookie() function do not write the cookie value. I've tested by echo-ing the cookie value both on my localhost and on my live server. $_COOKIE[] value on localhost is showing but not with the one in the live server.

I thought maybe it's related to the $expire time zone like the one's in this post http://anupraj.com.np/index.php/php-cookies-not-working-php-cookie-tutorial-and-scirpt/14 . But then I realized that I've set the cookies to expire in 1 month, not only in one hour like on that blog post. So I think that's not the case.

This is the content of setting.php

```
<?php
$defaultSettings['default_post_to'] = 'both';
$defaultSettings['timesince_style'] = 'simplify';
...
$defaultSettings['display_geo_info'] = 'true';
$defaultSettings['enable_javascript'] = 'true';

if(!isset($_COOKIE['settings'])){
    setcookie("settings", serialize($defaultSettings), time()+3600*24*30);
    header('Location: index.php');
}
$setting = unserialize($_COOKIE['settings']);
?>
```

And this is content of index.php

```
<?php
/*
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
*/

session_start();

require_once("settings.php"); // Settings files
require_once('varlib.php'); // Get all possible passed variable
require_once('auth.php'); // Check for channel login status

// If inputbar form submitted
if( $_POST['inputbox'] ){
...
}
else{
    echo "SETTING COOKIE: <br/><br/>";
    // This print_r is only showing the $_COOKIE value (which is stored on $setting) on localhost but no on live server
        print_r($setting);
    switch( $com ){
        ...
    }
}
?>
```

I've search about it everywhere (Google, stackoverflow, asking friends on twiiter/FB) still no solutions

I hope some body could give me the solution here
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you try the path and domain parameters of setcookie()?

Comment: If you enable error_reporting, you don't get any error-message?

Comment: @Kamal: Compare the local and live server's `phpinfo()` output for the `session` part (where cookie settings are also shown).

Comment: @rik: not yet, I'll try it soon

Comment: @Dr.Molle: I got a lot of warning with the other section of my code actually :p but none of its are related to this cookie problem

Comment: @stealthyninja: I've compared it, these are some differences:

Comment: How can you be so sure? If warnings/errors result in any output, your cookies cannot be set.

Comment: LIVE SERVER: Registered serializer handlers: php php_binary; session.hash_bits_per_character:4; session.use_only_cookies: On;

Comment: LOCALHOST: Registered serializer handlers: php php_binary wddx; session.hash_bits_per_character:5; session.use_only_cookies: Off;

Comment: @Dr.Molle: mmm... don't know for sure actually, but I don't see any cookie related error/warning messages on those warning message

Comment: @Dr.Molle: just lots of undefined index like this: Notice: Undefined index: page in D:\xampp\htdocs\Litwe\litwe\varlib.php on line 23

Comment: Actually, on Stack Overflow, when you have solved your own problem you should post the solution as an answer, and mark *that* as accepted, instead of prepending '[solved]' to your question's title

Comment: @Yi Jiang: hoho... thanks for the info, I'm a newbie here :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at both path and domain parameters for the setcookie function.
Reference: setcookie @ PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Try this to set your cookie:

```
if ($on_localhost) { // change this
    $domain = '.localhost';
} else {
    $domain = '.webhoster.com'; // change this
}
setcookie(
    'settings',
    serialize($defaultSettings),
    time()+3600*24*30,
    '/',          // this is the path
    $domain       // this is the domain
);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Probably your server time is not correct therefore Cookeis are not working on server.

Try this:

```
setcookie("settings", serialize($defaultSettings), 0);
```

Setting expiration to zero will fix your issue in this case. or update your server time.

Answer (score 1):

While applying solutions we get forgot the basic of Cookies.

Cookies are like headers. Like the headers, it should be sent before any output generates. then only it sets successfully. I have struggled a lot for this problem but when i went through the basics this problem got solved quickly.

this syntax will be enough to solve this problem...

```
setcookie(
'settings',
serialize($defaultSettings),
time()+3600*24*30,
'/'          // this is the path
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setcookie("settings", serialize($defaultSettings), time()+3600*24*30, '/'); // added path
```

Also, could it be that `serialize($defaultSettings)` result is too large?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your clue. I found that it seems the problem is about the serialize()/unserialize() function. The serialize function did work, but the unserialize() function seems return nothing. Is it really because it's too large?

Comment: Cookie size is usually limited to 4 KB

Answer (score 0):

Try  `exit()` after the Location-header.

A Location-header does not prevent a PHP-script from executing further instructions, maybe there is something executed after the header that causes the misbehaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Only initialize the ob_start() method before setcookie(). most of the developer ob_start() method include in config file.