# Why is setcookie not working on server?

Tags: php, cookies

I am using this code

```
setcookie("we", 2, time()+3600*24*365);
echo "'".$_COOKIE["we"]."'";
```

to set a cookie for my site.

This works fine on localhost and I get `'2'` however when I run this on my online site I get `''`. Why is this happening?

**UPDATE** 
I am trying this code to test my cookie problem

```
$c = "cookiesfwefwfwef";
if(isset($_COOKIE[$c])){
    echo "The cookie '".$c."' is going to be destroyed";
    setcookie($c, 23,  time()-3600*24*365, $site_url);
}else{
    echo "The cookie '".$c."' is going to be set";
    setcookie($c, 23,  time()+3600*24*365, $site_url);
}
```

The problem is that every time I refresh my browser on my online site I keep getting `The cookie 'cookiesfwefwfwef' is going to be set`, however when I refresh my browser on my localhsot site I get `The cookie 'cookiesfwefwfwef' is going to be set` then `The cookie 'cookiesfwefwfwef' is going to be destroyed` then `The cookie 'cookiesfwefwfwef' is going to be set`and so on.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I found one similar to this, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427743/php-cookies-works-well-on-localhost-but-its-not-working-on-live-server

Comment: If you found answer helpful then please mark it.

Comment: @Parixit,  I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`setcookie()` will set COOKIE on browser side after your server sends response to browser. So you can not user `$_COOKIE` within same request.

After setcookie, when browser sends request again at that time you will get value of `$_COOKIE`.

If you want to use `$_COOKIE` within same request, then kindly assign value to it like this:
`$_COOKIE["we"] = 2;`

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

cookie value will be printed on the next page refresh also you haven't specified the cookie path.

```
setcookie("we", 2, strtotime("+1 year"), "/");
echo "'".$_COOKIE["we"]."'";
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look.