# The cookie in not working on the server but it works perfectly on localhost, what should i do?

Tags: php

I have created a voting system in core PHP and used cookies so that one cannot give vote twice, and the code is perfectly working on the localhost but it does not work on the live server.
I am using `GoDaddy` hosting and have uploaded the folder in my primary domain the path is mydomain.com/election

```
<?php  
    include("connection.php");
    if(isset($_COOKIE['vote']))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('You cannot vote again.');</script>";

        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_POST['modi']))
        {
            $name = 'vote';
            $value = '1';
            setcookie($name, $value, time()+1*365*24*60*60, '/', 'technoamazon.com', 0);

            $modi = mysqli_query($con, "update election set modi=modi+1");
            if($modi)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('You have voted to Shri Narendra Modi.');</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";
            }
        }
        if(isset($_POST['rahul']))
        {
            $name = 'vote';
            $value = '1';
            setcookie($name, $value, time()+1*365*24*60*60, '/', 'technoamazon.com', 0);
            $rahul = mysqli_query($con, "update election set rahul=rahul+1");
            if($rahul)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('You have voted to Shri Rahul Gandhi.');</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

the above code is working properly in localhost but not works on the server

Comment: I think it's not cookies problem, maybe the problem is on `unserialize()` function. The serialized cookie which being the parameter of that function must be stripslash-ed first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Cookies works well on localhost, but it's not working on live server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427743/php-cookies-works-well-on-localhost-but-its-not-working-on-live-server)

Comment: @Roshan there is no `unserialize` in the post, how do you get this conclusion?

Comment: Is the domain `technoamazon.com` a right one?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427743/php-cookies-works-well-on-localhost-but-its-not-working-on-live-server

Comment: yes @shingo the domain is right